# How is an Android application installed?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

What program installs other applications? Is it the package installer or some other internal system application? I stopped the package installer manually, but when I access Google Play from my browser and install an app from there, it automatically installs regardless.

What application or process is responsible for installing applications from the Google Play Store?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain it's PackageInstaller.apk that handles the installation of apps. It's in /system/apps. This is the interface that gives you the option of cancel/install and reads you the permissions.

However, installing directly from the Google Play store you bypass those screens and it's a direct download. It's seemingly downloads and installs the apk directly to your device's data without the Package Installer.

Hope that helps. If you provide more info on what you'd like to accomplish, then we can assist you further.